# Why Ruby on Rails' Enumerable shows count of 3 but ".each" prints out item 1 time only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, enumerable

I have a Enumerable object returned from Mongoid (MongoDB object mapper)

using HAML:

```
= @employees.count       
= @employees.class

- @employees.each do |e|
  =h e.inspect
```

the count shows 3
the class shows Enumerable::Enumerator
But only 1 item is printed out

the object is returned in the controller using

```
@employees = Employee.limit(3).where({:_id.gte => startID.to_i})
```

If I change

```
- @employees.each do |e|
```

to

```
- @employees.to_a.each do |e|
```

then it prints out all 3, but why will the Enumerable method fail?  If I try in rails console using `p e` it actually prints out 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `@employees` is not lazy, but that it's a problem with your haml.

Try doing the equivalent of this in haml:

```
<ul>
= @employees.map { |e| "<li>" + e.inspect + "</li>" }.join
</ul>
```

Ok, just read through some haml docs, does this work for you?

```
- @employees.each do |e|
    %p= h e.inspect
```